# Reset system file permissions modified by disabling system integrity protection

Tags: catalina, permission, sip

Is there a way to reset permissions on (and/or fully restore) files protected by System Integrity Protection?

I realize I have had SIP disabled for a while now and I want to make sure system files are not modified and permissions are identical to those of a fresh installation, without having to reinstall macOS. In macOS Catalina, the traditional 'Repair disk permissions' has been removed since SIP prevents modification of system files anyway.

Comment: To modify system files (with SIP disabled) you would have to mount your system volume readwrite after each reboot additionally! Check your shell's history file, whether you did this (`sudo mount -rw /`) in the past. If you modified your system volume booted to macOS recovery it won't appear in the history, but you probably would remember doing something like this.

Comment: @klanomath So you are saying my computer logs all changes to system files as long as it's done without booting into recovery mode? If so, how would I go about accessing these logs?

Comment: It's the shell history file (not one of the log files!): either ~/.bash_history or ~/.zhistory logged in as admin user (if you didn't change the hist names - the latter is the default after moving to zsh with Catalina).

Comment: There's also a 3rd-party command line tool [RepairPermissions V3](https://www.firewolf.science/download/806/) [direct d/l] (site: [RepairPermissions V3 – Now supports repairing permissions on macOS Mojave](https://www.firewolf.science/2016/07/repairpermissions-v3-now-supports-repairing-permissions-on-macos-mojave/)) to repair file and folder permissions of boot volumes up to macOS Mojave **but not** Catalina.